# FFMPEG - scale and chromakey not working together?

Tags: ffmpeg, chromakey, scale

video1.mp4 1280×720, with a green area

video2.mp4 1280×720

I need to reduce video2.mp4 to 640x480 and insert what fits into the green area of video1.mp4

I went through all the options that I found on the Internet, but they don't work in my case.

An example that reduces, but the chromakey does not work:

`ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]colorkey=0x00b200:0.02:0.03[v0];[1]scale=800:640[v1];[v0][v1]overlay[out]" -codec:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset slow -map "[out]" -map 0:a result.mp4`

Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: try to increase similarity `0.02` to `0.2` and, maybe, reverse `[v1][v0]overlay`?

Comment: "similarity 0.02 to 0.2", - it didn't help. If reverse [v1][v0]overlay then the chromakey is triggered, but the output video is cropped to size 640x480.

Comment: tested by this way `ffmpeg -i "switch.mp4" -i "input 1.mp4" -filter_complex "
[0]colorkey=#5fc502:0.1:0[v0];
[1]scale=640:480,pad=1280:720:-1:-1[v1];
[v1][v0]overlay
" -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 23 -c:a copy -t 5 /tmp/output.mkv`